# Proper way to distribute Bonjour enabled Windows application

Tags: windows, bonjour

I am quite confused as to the proper way of distributing Bonjour as a part of a Windows application that would publish a service for a client iOS app.

No matter how much I google around, I cannot find a clear how-to guide. It would be great if someone could provide guidelines.

The main reasons of my confusion are:

- Is it mandatory to distribute the entire bonjour Win SDK as a part of my Win application?
- Since Apple provides source code to build mDNSResponder.exe, is it sufficient to only distribute such file along with dns-sd.dll?
- What is the intended purpose of providing sources for mDNSResponder.exe otherwise?
- What is the recommended way to handle the possibility of having Bonjour already installed on the system?
- Also, where can I find the latest Bonjour SDK (3.x I guess?), I can only find 2.0.4. Is it only accessible if I am enrolled in the OSX developer program? (I am enrolled in iOS developer program for now.)

Many thanks.

Answer (score 2):

This is information I gathered from various sources, including communications with official Apple support. I report it in the way I believe to be accurate, I hope it can be useful (no liability assumed!).

For Bonjour-enabled Windows application you have basically two main options:

- Bundle the Bonjour Installer with your application (which is not the Bonjour SDK, the SDK if for your own developer use only).

  If you choose to do so, the Bonjour installer must be called from your own installer during the installation process. The possibility of Bonjour being already installed in the system is totally handled by the Bonjour installer.

  And here come some bad news: you **must** include de Bonjour Logo on your physical distribution medium (like a DVD cover sleeve) according to the Apple guidelines specified in the Windows Bundling Agreement, and you need Apple approval before distributing your product.
- Do not bundle. I.e., do not distribute Bonjour with your application but simply use it if already present in the system. If you do not distribute Bonjour in any form the whole Windows Bundling Agreement simply does not apply. You application should search for the `dnssd.dll` and load it dynamically if found.

  Consider that most of Windows users would have Bonjour already installed   due to the fact that some popular apps use it (for example iTunes and Skype).

Comment: What about linking with the code which is released as open source by Apple, then checking for an existing Bonjour/mdnsResponder at runtime. If none is available, use the one in your application.

Comment: I'm not sure, but when I was looking into this I didn't find any way through even if you build your own dnssd.

Comment: Do i need to post them the signed license agreement and include the logo in my software even if my product is completely software?

Answer (score 1):

While the source code of Bonjour is released under an open-source library (Apache License, Version 2.0) this does not require Apple to do anything. In particular, they do not need to document how you'd use this license.

The license allows you to use and adapt Apple's source code, including its copyright, but not including its trademark "Bonjour(TM)". Since this is the standard Apache license, you don't have the requirement either to show the trademark.

So, to answer your questions:

- No, you can build your own version of Bonjour from source and use that under the Apache license. You can't call it Bonjour, but why do you need a name in the first place? "mDNS" would be a reasonable choice, possibly prefixed with *your* trademark.
- It seems sufficient to distribute the DLL and EXE. Arranging how they find each other might benefit from some tailoring, so your own build of Bonjour doesn't clash with Apple's.
- (I won't speculate on Apple's motives)
- The design problem here is that Bonjour acts as a system service, and services are inherently singletons. If you install it unmodified, Apple wouldn't be able to install its own build. That's not a legal problem, probably, but it is a bad customer experience. Installing your own build as a distinct service would avoid the clash, allowing both versions to co-exist.
- (Resource request, off-topic)